# Iterate through multiple @ViewChild instances of the same component angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, angular2-components

I have an Ionic 2 application with a ParentComponent calling ChildComponent @ViewChild method to fire up multiple ChildComponents. One of the ChildComponents get's instantiated twice in the view with different parameters like so:

```
<ChildComponent [startFrom]="0" [limitTo]="1"></ChildComponent>
<ChildComponent [startFrom]="1" [limitTo]="1"></ChildComponent>
```

After an offline/online device state change, I call ChildComponent's method to update a list of items it returns.

```
@ViewChild(ChildComponent) childComponent: ChildComponent;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.networkService.connectSubscription(() => {
        this.childComponent.getItems();
    });
}
```

The issue here is `this.childComponent` only get's hold of the first ChildComponent instance of the two.

Is there a way to iterate through multiple instances of the same @ViewChild component so I could do something like `this.childComponent1.getItems()` and `this.childComponent2.getItems()`?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@ViewChildren(ChildComponent) childComponents: QueryList<ChildComponent>;
```

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.networkService.connectSubscription(() => {
        this.childComponents.toArray();
    });
}
```

Comment: Absolutely. The annoying part is I got right to this line by myself `this.childComponents` but didn't know about `toArray()`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I know, this isn't easy to discover.